# Rename pdf files to <string1>_<string2>.pdf where <string1>, <string2> are inside pdf file

Tags: pdf, regex

I have 50.000-60.000 pdf documents.
In each document i have patient ID in format [8 0 0 5 2 5 0 0 3 9 0] - 11 digits with spaces between digits. I need to change filename to 80052500390_2019-04-19.pdf.
First 6 digits is date of birth (YY-MM-DD)
How to search pdf for regex and rename filename?

I use forfiles and pdfgrep to find files:

```
forfiles /S /M *.pdf /C "cmd /c pdfgrep.exe -H -r -P \d{11} @file "
```

But i dont know, how to rename files using results:

```
MISZ BO»ENA - Tomografia komputerowa mˇzgu 43802.pdf:PESEL: 67032200225
MISZKIEWICZ MARIANNA - Tomografia komputerowa klatki piersiowej 44160.pdf:40120101512
MISZKIEWICZ WOJCIECH - Rezonans magnetyczny prawego stawu kolanowego 44270.pdf:80052500390
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  1. Is the 21 character patient ID string the entire contents of the pdf?  If not, there isn't enough information here to understand the requirements of the task.  What range of conditions could exist in the records?  Where would the ID be found?  What might surround it?  How unique a pattern is it?  Does the record contain only plain ASCII text?  Is the requirement to search each entire file for the first instance of any 11 digits separated by spaces, regardless of adjacent characters?  Is each file guaranteed to contain one and only one such target?   (cont'd)

Comment: 2. Where are all of the 50-60K files (all in one directory)?  What do the current names look like?  The task will require some form of location and iteration through the files and you don't provide enough information to address that.  Please provide a more detailed description of the files.  Also, be aware that the site is not intended as a free coding service, but people will help you solve a specific issue you encounter trying to do it yourself.  Your question will get a much better reception if you describe your own research and efforts, and where you're stuck.

Comment: This ID look like 
PESEL: 80052500390
or
P E S E L : 8 0 0 5 2 5 0 0 3 9 0
or 
[ 8 0 0 5 2 5 0 0 3 9 0 ]
This is polish unique personal identity number which checksum. First 8 digits is date of birth (YYYY-MM-DD).
All files are in one directory on NAS (//nas-ip/studies/archive)

Comment: One file is description of one study for one patient.

Comment: I really hope the example consists of made-up data. Publishing actual medical records and/or PESELs may lead to legal problems in Poland, I think.

Comment: Your example doesn't match the description.  In your example, there are no inter-character spaces.  If these are all coming from the same source, it would be surprising to see it formatted both ways.  It isn't clear what you're dealing with.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - this are fake pesel numbers, 2 fake names and my name as last one

Comment: The rule \d{11} find a pesel like 80052500390. I dont know how to find pesel with spaces between digits.